# How to check if the value in the array does not exist?

Tags: vb.net

How to check if the value in the array is higher.
My case I have Designpoints count =12 and FromNode value =11. The problem is that DesignPoints(12) does not exist since Designpoints start count from 0.I get an error in **"If Designpoints(FromNode + 1).tag = "WALL" Then"**
Gets and error
"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

```
For gcount = 0 To GroundPoints.Count - 2
   For Dcount = 0 To Designpoints.Count - 2
      If Designpoints(FromNode + 1).tag = "WALL" Then
        polygon.PolyGonType = XpolyType.StructureCut
        customPolygon.Add(polygon)
      Else
```

Is there any way to check if the FromNode value is always less than the Designpoints value.
I tried to check the condition like

```
If Designpoints.count > FromNode + 1 And Designpoints(FromNode + 1).tag = "WALL" Then
```

Also tried putting "Designpoints(FromNode + 1).tag = "WALL" " inside the "If Designpoints.count > FromNode + 1" loop

Comment: Use `AndAlso` instead of `And`. The latter always evaluates both sides, thus even if your left statement determines that it is out of range, it will still check the right one as well.

Comment: I read somewhere AndAlso is used for numeric comparison only. So I did not tried it, Thank you any way.